# Android TableLayout rows and columns evenly distributed

Tags: android, grid, imagebutton, tablelayout, scaletype

I have a problem with Table layout to get ImageButtons evenly distributed in grid 3x4. Below is used code to achieve this. There is fitXY (images get stretched unnaturally in horizontally or vertically). Where I have fitCenter images in last row has been not square and looks odd in comparison with other images (all images are square). This images in last row was horizontally narrowed.

*** I also have question what about TableLayout and weight="1" + match_parent every where and if one image will have 100x100px and other 400x400px I noticed that this regular grid was totally messed up. What is the best practice to achieve such regular grid of buttons? ***

[image: icon grid]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bigben"
android:id="@+id/moreappsSwipeLayout">
<TableLayout 
android:id="@+id/MoreAppsActivityTable"
android:layout_above="@id/swipe_instruction"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
android:layout_marginRight="30dp">
<TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01" 
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1">
     <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/downloadEnglishBtn"
            android:contentDescription="@string/english_lang"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/en_favicon"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"       
      />
      <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/downloadSpanishBtn"
        android:contentDescription="@string/spanish_lang"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@+drawable/es_favicon"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"         
        />
       <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/downloadGermanBtn"
        android:contentDescription="@string/german_lang"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@+drawable/de_favicon"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"         
        />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow02" 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1">
     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/downloadFrenchBtn"
        android:contentDescription="@string/french_lang"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@+drawable/fr_favicon"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/downloadItalianBtn"
        android:contentDescription="@string/italian_lang"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@+drawable/it_favicon" 
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
        />
     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/downloadPolishBtn"
        android:contentDescription="@string/polish_lang"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@+drawable/pl_favicon" 
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
        />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow03" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/downloadPortugueseBtn"
        android:contentDescription="@string/portuguese_lang"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@+drawable/pt_favicon"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
       />
     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/downloadRussianBtn"
        android:contentDescription="@string/russian_lang"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@+drawable/ru_favicon" 
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
       />
      <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/downloadDutchBtn"
        android:contentDescription="@string/dutch_lang"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@+drawable/nl_favicon" 
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
       />
    </TableRow>
     <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow04" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/downloadRomanianBtn"
        android:contentDescription="@string/romanian_lang"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@+drawable/ro_favicon"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
       />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/downloadTurkishBtn"
        android:contentDescription="@string/turkish_lang"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@+drawable/tr_favicon" 
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
       />
     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/downloadArabicBtn"
        android:contentDescription="@string/arabic_lang"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@+drawable/ar_favicon" 
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
       />
  </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>

  <TextView
   android:id="@+id/swipe_instruction"
   android:text="@string/swipe_instruction"  
   android:textColor="#000000"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I found the problem this was associated with this that some images have different size i.e. 78x78px and 100x100px but its odd that there can not be differently sized images and that aren't fit properly